# JavaFX LineChart in a loop increases memory useage with time

Tags: java, javafx

JavaFX LineChart consumes more memory in a loop with time

I am using eclipse for JavaFX and am trying to convert UDP data that I am receiving continuously to plot it on a linechart but this causes increasing memory useage it starts from 200 MB and reaches to about 2GB. I have looked this problem everywhere but can't seem to find any solution help pls.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(meterplus>=10) {
              graphsubtractor++;
              vertSpdSeries.getData().remove(0);
              groundSpdSeries.getData().remove(0);
              altitudeSeries.getData().remove(0);
              xAxis.setLowerBound((graphsubtractor));
              xAxis.setUpperBound((graphsubtractor)+10);
              xAxis1.setLowerBound((graphsubtractor));
              xAxis1.setUpperBound((graphsubtractor)+10);
              xAxis2.setLowerBound((graphsubtractor));
              xAxis2.setUpperBound((graphsubtractor)+10);
              //xAxis.

        }
        //1System.out.println("LINE CHART SIZE: "+lineChart2.get);
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        altitudeSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(meterplus,
        Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0).getValue())));
        vertSpdSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(meterplus,                                          
        Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(3).getValue())));
        groundSpdSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(meterplus,                                                        
        Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(1).getValue())));

      }
});
```

When I comment the code to update the chart the application consumes just 150 MB constantly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] demonstrating the issue (and format your code properly).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask